# combine two pd df by index and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data looks like this:

```
df1 =           456089.0  456091.0  456093.0 
5428709.0       1.0       1.0       NaN  
5428711.0       1.0       1.0       NaN
5428713.0       NaN       NaN       1.0

df2 =           456093.0  456095.0  456097.0 
5428711.0       2.0       NaN       NaN  
5428713.0       NaN       2.0       NaN
5428715.0       NaN       NaN       2.0
```

I would like to have this output:

```
df3 =           456089.0  456091.0  456093.0  456095.0  456097.0 
5428709.0       1.0       1.0       NaN       NaN       NaN  
5428711.0       1.0       1.0       2.0       NaN       NaN
5428713.0       NaN       NaN       1.0       2.0       NaN
5428715.0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       2.0
```

I tried several combinations with pd.merge, pd.join, pd.concat but nothing worked the way I want it, since I want to combine the data by index and column.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `sum` with `concat`

```
out = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sum(axis=1,level=0,min_count=1).sum(axis=0,level=0,min_count=1)
Out[150]: 
           456089.0  456091.0  456093.0  456095.0  456097.0
5428709.0       1.0       1.0       NaN       NaN       NaN
5428711.0       1.0       1.0       2.0       NaN       NaN
5428713.0       NaN       NaN       1.0       2.0       NaN
5428715.0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       2.0
```

Comment: concat on axis 1 would also do : `pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=1).sum(level=0,axis=1,min_count=1)`